# JWKTL - Can't connect to database

Tags: java, wiktionary

I'm trying to install the JWKTL library into a Java project. 
[JWKTL Getting started](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-jwktl/documentation/getting-started/)

Now I downloaded the dump file as described, and parsed it into a new directory.

My code is:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.JWKTL;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.IWiktionaryEdition;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.IWiktionaryEntry;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.IWiktionaryPage;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.IWiktionaryRelation;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.PartOfSpeech;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.RelationType;


public class Main {

    final static String PATH_TO_DUMP_FILE = "/GetWords/enwiktionary-20160601-pages-articles-multistream.xml";
    final static String TARGET_DIRECTORY = "/GetWords/";
    final static boolean OVERWRITE_EXISTING_FILES = true;
    /**
     * Simple example which parses an English dump file and prints the entries for the word <i>Wiktionary</i>
     * @param args name of the dump file, output directory for parsed data, ISO language code of the Wiktionary entry language (en/de), boolean value that specifies if existing parsed data should be deleted
     */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            File dumpFile = new File(PATH_TO_DUMP_FILE);
              File outputDirectory = new File(TARGET_DIRECTORY);
              boolean overwriteExisting = OVERWRITE_EXISTING_FILES;

              JWKTL.parseWiktionaryDump(dumpFile, outputDirectory, overwriteExisting);

              IWiktionaryEdition wkt = JWKTL.openEdition(TARGET_DIRECTORY);

              //TODO: Query the data you need.

              // Close the database connection.
              wkt.close();
}
}
```

But the line: `IWiktionaryEdition wkt = JWKTL.openEdition(TARGET_DIRECTORY);` throws an error: `The method openEdition(File) in the type JWKTL is not applicable for the arguments (String)`, when I try to enter the dump_file as
*java.io.File*

the program throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.WiktionaryException: Unable to establish a db connection
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.entry.BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.<init>(BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.java:228)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.entry.BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.<init>(BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.java:205)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.JWKTL.openEdition(JWKTL.java:98)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.JWKTL.openEdition(JWKTL.java:89)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbConfigManager.applyFileConfig(DbConfigManager.java:388)
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.setupHandleConfig(Environment.java:323)
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:260)
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:212)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.entry.BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.connect(BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.java:241)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.jwktl.api.entry.BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.<init>(BerkeleyDBWiktionaryEdition.java:224)
    ... 4 more
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I use Java 8 in Eclipse Mars.

I installed these libs:

- jwktl-1.0.1.jar
- je-6.4.25.jar
- apache-ant-1.8.2.jar

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it... 
It was too simple:

The sulution is:

```
File f = new File(TARGET_DIRECTORY);

IWiktionaryEdition wkt = JWKTL.openEdition(f);
```

Best regards!